# Strange results while nesting scope constructs?

Tags: scoping

I did a handful of tests with `Block`, `With`, and `Module` and had a couple of *new* surprises. First, I explicitly nested all pairs, producing the following nine tests, naively expecting 37 in each case:

```
{Block[{x=42}, Block[ {x=37},x]],
 Block[{x=42}, With[  {x=37},x]],
 Block[{x=42}, Module[{x=37},x]],
 With[ {x=42}, Block[ {x=37},x]],
 With[ {x=42}, With[  {x=37},x]],
 With[ {x=42}, Module[{x=37},x]],
 Module[{x=42},Block[ {x=37},x]],
 Module[{x=42},With[  {x=37},x]],
 Module[{x=42},Module[{x=37},x]]}
```

> During evaluation of In[48]:= Block::lvset: Local variable
>   specification {42=37} contains 42=37, which is an assignment to 42;
>   only assignments to symbols are allowed. >>
>
> Out[48]= {37, 37, 37, Block[{42 = 37}, 42], 37, 37, 37, 37, 37}

The surprise is that `With...Block...` produces a collision, but `With...With...` and `With...Module...` don't.

UNLESS, I try the test this way

```
With[{heads={Block,With,Module}},
  Table[heads[[i]][{x=42},heads[[j]][{x=37},x]],{i,3},{j,3}]]
```

> During evaluation of In[49]:= Block::lvset: Local variable
>   specification {42=37} contains 42=37, which is an assignment to 42;
>   only assignments to symbols are allowed. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[49]:= With::lvset: Local variable
>   specification {42=37} contains 42=37, which is an assignment to 42;
>   only assignments to symbols are allowed. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[49]:= Module::lvset: Local variable
>   specification {42=37} contains 42=37, which is an assignment to 42;
>   only assignments to symbols are allowed. >>
>
> Out[49]= {{37, 37, 37}, {Block[{42 = 37}, 42], With[{42 = 37}, 42],
>   Module[{42 = 37}, 42]}, {37, 37, 37}}

in which case ALL the `With...` cases produce collisions.

I thought I was starting to understand MMA's scoping constructs :(

**EDIT**: in case my question wasn't clear, I'd be grateful for the following explanations in more detail than the documentation offers: (1) why `x`  collides in the explicit `With...Block...` case, (2) why `x` collides in two more cases when the nesting constructs are built using `Table` instead of explicitly.

it occurred to me late to include `Function` and `Table` in the mix of scoping constructs, since they also give temporary bindings to variables. But I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: And your question is what?

Comment: Otherwise, the `With`-`Block` situation is pretty clear, when you look at the trace: `Block[{42 = 37}, 42]`. The `With`-`With` situation is explained in the more information doc.

Comment: Explained my question in the EDIT above.  I did not understand the documentation well enough to predict these collisions, and would be grateful for a more explicit and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think, your main reported puzzle - the collision in the `With` - `Block` case can be understood by recalling that `Block` is a dynamic scoping construct, not lexical. The most important difference in our present context is that for dynamic scoping, its influence is felt by the code very late - only at the evaluation stage, because symbols' values are being localized rather than symbols' names. Therefore, `Block` presents no "danger" whatsoever, for its enclosing scoping constructs, be those lexical or dynamic.

The main essence of the "inner scoping construct wins" rule is to protect the inner scoping constructs from lexical bindings performed by outer scoping constructs, since lexical scoping constructs evaluate from outside to inside, and introduce changes (variable bindings, or even replacements for `With`), *before* the actual evaluation. For `Block`, while variable bindings are happening early, the code itself is not modified in any way. So, it seems rather natural to me that the designers of Mathematica chose to not enforce the "inner scoping construct wins" when `Block` is the inner scoping construct.

It may help to present a very crude imitation of `Block` here:

```
ClearAll[myBlock];
SetAttributes[myBlock, HoldAll];
myBlock[{Set[var_Symbol, expr_]}, code_] :=
 With[{oldvar = var},
   var = expr;
   With[{result = code},
     Clear[var];
     If[oldvar =!= var, var = oldvar];
     result
   ]
 ]
```

While it does not have many desirable features that real `Block` has, it captures the essence of what `Block` does for simple variable (`OwnValues`) localization. For example:

```
myBlock[{x=37},x]

(*  37  *)

myBlock[{x=37},myBlock[{x= 42},x]]

(*  42  *)
```

Now, we can see what is happening in `With` - `Block` case:

```
With[{x=42},myBlock[{x=37},x]]

(*  myBlock[{42=37},42]  *)
```

which is exactly what also happens to built-in `Block`.

To summarize: I see the reason for the "inner scoping construct wins" not being enforced for `Block` because this rule only makes sense for lexical scoping constructs. This is so because lexical scoping constructs physically change the code before it executes (variable renaming for `Module`, expression substitution for `With`) , and can break inner scoping  constructs since those execute later. Since dynamic scoping constructs change variable *values*, but not code, there is no such danger for them.

As to the specific `With`-`Block` case, some contradiction is here even from the start: `With` signals that variables localized with it are local constants, so can not be changed in the body of `With`. `Block`, however, manifests that it localizes essentially variables, symbols that may have different values. One can also use it without a conflict in such a way:

```
Clear[x,y];  
With[{x = y}, Block[{x = 37}, x]]
```

where effectively `Block` localizes the `y` symbol, not `x`, as can be easily seen using `Trace`. Whether or not such uses can ever be constructive I don't know.

Comment: I still haven't read this and I'm already about to delete my playful innocent answer

Comment: @Rojo I think you shouldn't, I just finished reading it and you said in a shorter way many of the things I tried to explain here.

Comment: Took me longer to read yours. +1, an advanced answer

Comment: @Rojo Thanks, but I think you were essentially saying the same, I just went into somewhat greater detail.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin as to your last sentence, "constructive, I don't know", but "instructive" certainly :)

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Thanks, good to know. Thanks also for the accept.

Answer (score 12):

`Block` isn't respected as a scoping construct from the outside. Variables aren't renamed when something is injected inside by other scoping constructs, or by a replacement, like they are in `Module` and `With`. This makes some sense because `Block` doesn't do lexical scoping anyway

Your `Table` example can be explained by thinking about how a scoping construct can "respect" the inner constructs.

Imagine you are `With` (I hope you have good imagination). You receive some expression and you have to replace all the `x` by `37`. But you don't want to mess with certain structures. So, before doing the replacement, you scan for those structures, and avoid them... But, you haven't evaluated your argument, so you can't know if `Identity[Module][...]` will end up having a proper `Module[...]` structure or not. You simply don't recognise it as a `Module`, and you mess with it...

Then, you give Rojo an upvote and he goes to sleep

Comment: pleasant dreams :)