# Failure in integrating from an interpolating function!

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration, interpolation

Consider a list like below:

```
ttable={{0, 2.6596 - 66.137 I}, {1/9, 2.45339 - 65.3148 I}, {2/9, 
  1.82053 - 62.8922 I}, {1/3, 0.720006 - 58.9982 I}, {4/
  9, -0.911205 - 53.8382 I}, {5/9, -3.15056 - 47.6797 I}, {2/
  3, -6.08057 - 40.8346 I}, {7/9, -9.77826 - 33.6382 I}, {8/
  9, -14.3047 - 26.4282 I}, {1, -19.6947 - 19.5216 I}}`
```

by defining "f" as interpolating function we'll have:

```
f = Interpolation[ttable]
```

now we define ff as the following integration:

```
ff[\[Xi]_]:=NIntegrate[(f[rr]) Cos[rr \[Xi]], {rr, 0, 1}]
```

the first problem is that this function can not be calculated and I have no idea why the followoing error happens:

```
In[87]:= ff[.1]
During evaluation of In[87]:= NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Cos[rr \[Xi]] InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1.}},{4,15,0,{10},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},<<1>>,{
Developer`PackedArrayForm,{0,<<10>>},{2.6596 -66.137 I,<<8>>,-19.6947-19.5216 I}},{Automatic}][rr] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,0.111111}}. >>
Out[87]= NIntegrate[f[rr] Cos[rr \[Xi]],{rr,0,1}]
```

The other thing should be mentioned is that I have to use `ff` in integrand of  another integration like below:

```
NIntegrate[ff[\[Xi]] * \[Xi],{\[Xi],0,3}]
```

I've manipulated the former equations in many ways but none of them made an accurate output for the last integration, so I would be greatly thankful if somebody out there could help me!

Comment: Works like a charm for me on Mathematica 10.1 running on MacOS 10.10.3, just had to remove the apostrophe in the definition of `ttable`, which is probably a typo anyways.

Comment: @Wizard the ` ff ` function sometimes works and sometimes not which makes me really confused but what about the last integral could you calculate it too?! cause that one never showed to be solved!!!

Comment: about that apostrophe, yes that was a typo! and I'm using mathematica 10.0 running on windows 8 if it helps in any aspects!

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. `ff[.1]` evaluates to `-4.1238 - 48.0535 I` in V10.1 running on OS X (10.10.2).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem the user claims to be experiencing can not be reproduced.

Comment: @m_goldberg Dear sir could you calculate `NIntegrate[ff[\[Xi]] * \[Xi],{\[Xi],0,3}] ` too?!!!!

Comment: @m_goldberg I got the same error as posted by the OP, so I'm voting to leave this question open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most important information is that you used your function `ff` inside another `NIntegrate`, because this is the source of confusion. What you have to know is that `NIntegrate` doesn't start right away with the *numerical calculation* when you call

```
NIntegrate[ff[ξ]*ξ, {ξ, 0, 3}]
```

It will try to do some analysis of your integrand and most likely, it will try to evaluate `ff[ξ]` without putting in numbers. And what happens then? Right, you call the `NIntegrate` of `ff` without proper numerical value of `ξ`:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The solution is pretty simple: Change your definition of `ff` so that it only calls its `NIntegrate` body when the argument is indeed numeric:

```
ClearAll[ff];
ff[ξ_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(f[rr]) Cos[rr ξ], {rr, 0, 1}]
NIntegrate[ff[ξ]*ξ, {ξ, 0, 3}]

(* 4.28747 - 124.522 I *)
```

Comment: Sometimes I feel there should be a wrapper to perform this `NumericQ` trick automatically... and probably it's completely feasible(?)

Comment: @kirma, In V10.1 (OSX), I get the messages but the `NIntegrate` goes through and gets the right answer.  As you point out, the warnings are coming from the inside `NIntegrate`, but the outside `NIntegrate` seems not to care much.  One could view this as a compromise position, allowing the computation but warning the user in case it's a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Everthing woks out fine (in version 10 at least) if you take care of a consistent name of the integration variable.

Let's repeat all steps

1) Table of data

```
In[1]:= ttable = {{0, 2.6596 - 66.137 I}, {1/9, 2.45339 - 65.3148 I}, {2/9, 
   1.82053 - 62.8922 I}, {1/3, 
   0.720006 - 58.9982 I}, {4/9, -0.911205 - 53.8382 I}, {5/9, -3.15056 - 
    47.6797 I}, {2/3, -6.08057 - 40.8346 I}, {7/9, -9.77826 - 33.6382 I}, {8/9, -14.3047 - 26.4282 I}, {1, -19.6947 - 19.5216 I}};
```

2) Interpolation

```
In[2]:= f = Interpolation[ttable]
(* output skipped here *)
```

Check some values

```
f[#] & /@ {0, 1/2, 2/3, 1}

(*
Out[27]= {2.6596 - 66.137 I, -1.94971 - 50.8643 I, -6.08057 - 40.8346 I, -19.6947 - 19.5216 I}
*)
```

Plot real quantities derived from f

```
Plot[{Abs[f[x]], Re[f[x]], Im[f[x]]}, {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLabel -> "f[x] (Abs, Re, Im)"]
(* 150623_plot_f.jpg *)
```

[image]

3) Define ff

Clear[ff]

```
ff[z_] := NIntegrate[f[x] Cos[x z], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Plot the function ff

```
Plot[{Abs[ff[z]], Re[ff[z]], Im[ff[z]]}, {z, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLabel -> "ff[z] (Abs, Re, Im)"]
(* 150623_plot_ff.jpg *)
```

[image]

4) Finally define f1 as the definite numerical integral over ff

```
f1[y_] := NIntegrate[ff[x], {x, 0, y}]

f1[1.]

(* Out[39]= -2.94907 - 45.2287 I *)
```

No problem. So it seems. But if you would have chosen in the definition of f1 another name of the integration variable (x) than the name of the integration variable in the definition of ff then an error would appear. It sounds funny, but try it, take t instaed.

Comment: I'm probably going nuts here but for me it makes a difference whether I write `NIntegrate[ff[x], {x, 0, 1}]` which works fine, or whether I use `NIntegrate[ff[z], {z, 0, 1}]`, which gives a different result and throws errors.

Comment: And btw it seems your solution works fine because you used `x` and not `ξ` like OP did. Really weird

Comment: @ halirutan : 1) That is why I posted my answer. And, BTW, I was not telling WHY things are as they are but just how to solve the problem. 2) I could have as well used xi instead of y in the definition of ff. But I prefer latin letters in order to make the Mathematica text easier legible.

Comment: @halirutan `NIntegrate[ff[x], {x, 0, 1}]` yields the same errors for me as xi did.

Comment: My results are for "10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)". The integration which led to errors in your cases is that of my parapraph 4.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but rather a comment/example on @Dr.WolfgangHintze and @halirutan posts, concerning the "weird" behaviour that was observed with `NIntegrate`, that is localization and symbolic evaluation of the variables which may actually lead to unwanted results:

**Edit**

I'll take an even more simple example which concerns both `NIntegrate` and `Integrate`:

```
fNI[a_] := NIntegrate[a*hello, {hello, 0, 1}]
fI[a_]  :=  Integrate[a*hello, {hello, 0, 1}]
```

then ok:

```
fNI[1]
fI[1]
```

> `0.5`
>   `1/2`

**but**

```
fNI[hello]
fI[hello]
```

> `0.333333`
>   `1/3`

I would expect it to be rather `0.5 hello` and `1/2 hello` ?!

---

**Previous**

I'll take a very simple example:

Let's define:

```
f[a_] :=           NIntegrate[a*hello, {hello, 0, 1}]
fN[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a*hello, {hello, 0, 1}]
```

Would you expect:

```
NIntegrate[f[hello], {hello, 0, 1}]
```

> `0.333333`

which corresponds actually to `NIntegrate[NIntegrate[hello*hello, {hello, 0, 1}], {hello, 0, 1}]` !!!

whereas

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

> `0.25`

and

```
NIntegrate[fN[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> `0.25`

and

```
NIntegrate[fN[hello], {hello, 0, 1}]
```

> `0.25`

Comment: Note that `NIntegrate[f[hello], {hello, 1, 2}]` also gives `0.333333`: the outer integration range does not matter!

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Actually,  replacing `NIntegrate` by `Integrate` shows that : `Integrate[f[hello], {hello, a, b}]` returns `0.333333 (-a + b)`

Comment: It isn't surprising because `Integrate` does not have a `Hold*` attribute and `f[hello]` is evaluated *before* `Integrate`. So actually `Integrate[f[hello], {hello, a, b}]` is equivalent to `Integrate[0.333333, {hello, a, b}]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Actually i did not try to simply evaluate `f[hello]` ! See my edit.

Comment: All your observations are the *expected* and well-documented behavior (while may be not immediately obvious). For me the interesting observation was only the nested `NIntegrate` case which is identical to the [nested `Block` case](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9395/280): citing the Documentation, "`NIntegrate` effectively uses `Block` to localize variables." The `f[hello]` case is just [how the lexical scoping works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6236808/590388).